# Validar unique email Laravel | Tabelas Distintas

Tags: laravel-5, validação

Tenho uma dúvida com relação a validação de campo único no Laravel.
Tenho duas tabelas sem relacionamentos (`users` e `companies`), ambas possuem uma coluna `email`.

Preciso validar o campo `email` de forma única nas duas tabelas distintas, ou seja, na hora de cadastrar a empresa eu preciso verificar se o `email` existe na tabela `companies` e na tabela `users`.

Tentei fazer isso na validação

```
'email' => 'required|unique:companies' 
'email' => 'required|unique:users'
```

Não obtive sucesso nesta tentativa. Qual a melhor forma de se fazer isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvi meu problema fazendo um pequeno ajuste no código conforme abaixo:

```
'email' => 'required|unique:companies, email', 
'email' => 'required|unique:users, email',
```

Passei a coluna das tabelas na validação. Não sei porque mas acredito que da forma anterior deveria de ter funcionado...